# working in eclipse but not in online java compiler

Tags: java, exception

it shows java. util. no such element exception it is working perfectly in eclipse
but shows error in some online coding grounds

```
import java.util.*;

class outer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m;

        int n;
        System.out.println("enter the value of m");

        // System.out.println(x);
        m = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the value of n");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        // sc.close();
        if (m > 0 && n > 0) {

            if (m % 10 == n % 10)

            {
                System.out.println("true");
            } else {
                System.out.println("False");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlikely to find a JDK without `java.util` but I could be wrong. Can you provide what is that online compiler you are using ?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking here, but ... if i just count the amount of `{` (3) and the amount of `}` (5) they are not equal. Normally you should have the same amount of `{` as `}`

Comment: @AxelH you modified the code and probably "corrected" it

Comment: @f1sh I have only reformat using eclipse, it doesn't change the code (it look like I remove some `}` from SO versioning tool but I didn't, you can see the same amount of bracket added and removed. I am careful with the editing but I can do mistake of course. kvantour is wrong, he probably missed the class opening and both `if`. (a simple proof, I can run the original code...)